# Javascrip cannot access object properties from map method

Tags: javascript, arrays

So i have been having some problems with javascript's map method. For some reason i cannot access objects properties from map function. Even though i am using the function on an array. When i print out the object the output is;

[Output of console.log(marker)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIjr.png)

[this is the output of console.log(hospitalMarkers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oouKH.png)

And this is the code i use

[Code i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srSV0.png)

In the console log, if i print the marker, it shows me the whole list Which it should only be one of the elements. So if i try to access any properties of the objects from the marker, i get undefined.

Been trying to understand what's wrong for hours now and i am very close to losing it. What is wrong here ?

Comment: is the output picture from console.log(marker) or console.log(hospitalMarkers)?

Comment: Forgot to add it, it's from hospitalMarkers. But if i console.log(marker) it will print out an array too.

Comment: are you saying both arrays have no difference?

Comment: I will add the output pictures to  the question in a few minutes.

Comment: Post _code_ not _images of code_. Also see [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have to make a guess your structure is this.

```
    hospitalMarkers =  [ [... markers Array 1], [... markers Array 2]]
or hospitalMarkers = [ [{Ad:1},{Ad:2}], [{Ad:3},{Ad:4}]]
```

so it's a nested array

what you might be needing is:

```
    hospitalMarkers.flat().map(() => { console.log(marker.Ad)    });
 // flat it make it come one level up
 // hospitalMarkers = hospitalMarkers = [ {Ad:1},{Ad:2},{Ad:3},{Ad:4}]
```

this way you will have all the markers at the same level.

Comment: Yep, that really did it ! Thanks a lot for your help, i didn't know about flat function before.